# Replace text lines following matching line

Tags: sed

The file I'm working with looks like this:

```
#
# Bulk mode
#
#define command {
#       command_name    process-service-perfdata-file
#       command_line    /usr/libexec/pnp4nagios/process_perfdata.pl --bulk /var/log/pnp4nagios/service-perfdata
#}

#define command {
#       command_name    process-host-perfdata-file
#       command_line    /usr/libexec/pnp4nagios/process_perfdata.pl --bulk /var/log/pnp4nagios/host-perfdata
#}

#
# Bulk with NPCD mode
#
#define command {
#       command_name    process-service-perfdata-file
#       command_line    /bin/mv /var/log/pnp4nagios/service-perfdata /var/spool/pnp4nagios/service-perfdata.$TIMET$
#}

#define command {
#       command_name    process-host-perfdata-file
#       command_line    /bin/mv /var/log/pnp4nagios/host-perfdata /var/spool/pnp4nagios/host-perfdata.$TIMET$
#}
```

I'd like to uncomment all the lines following the "Bulk with NPCD mode" header. What I've got so far uncomments everything, *including the header*:

```
sed -E '/Bulk with NPCD mode/,$ {s/^#(.+)/\1/}' /etc/pnp4nagios/misccommands.cfg
```

How can I have it move ahead to skip the "Bulk with NPCD mode" line before doing any substitutions? I tried the `n` command, but moving to the next line seems to stop any further processing of the remaining lines:

```
sed -E '/Bulk with NPCD mode/,$ {n; s/^#(.+)/\1/}' /etc/pnp4nagios/misccommands.cfg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a range is the right approach, however, `sed` includes the range borders into the range, that's why you need to explicitly skip the starting line which contains the search pattern:

```
sed '/Bulk with NPCD/,${/Bulk with NPCD/!s/^#//}'
```

Btw, `s/^#//` replaces the hash at the start of the line.

Comment: As you can see I'm familiar with ranges already, but it was the `/Bulk with NPCD/!` syntax to skip a line that I was unfamiliar with. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh yes. I should haven read the question more carefully. Glad to see that it works!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^#.*mode$/h;//!G;/\n# Bulk with NPCD mode$/{/^#\n\|^# Bulk with NPCD mode\n/!s/^#//};P;d' file
```

Store the current mode in the hold space and append it to every line. If the current mode is `Bulk with NPCD mode` then remove the comment character if it is not the mode comment line or an empty comment.